# Symfony - clone edit and persist

Tags: symfony, persist

I'm trying to clone and edit both objects (source & cloned) after form submission and persist it.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->detach($ev2);
$clonedev = clone $ev;
$clonedev->setUpdatedAt(new \Datetime());
$clonedev->setCreatedAt(new \Datetime());
$clonedev->setReportInvitation(null);
$em->persist($clonedev);
$em->flush();
$ev->setReportedto($clonedev->getId());
$em->persist($ev2);
$em->flush();
```

the source object is getting changed too .

Comment: what is really your need, not only the technical part ?

Answer (score 0):

In your entity, implement the `__clone` method to erase the id when cloning the object:

```
public function __clone()
{
    $this->id = null;
}
```

Comment: I already did that.
when I dump the newly created object it shows that his id NULL